# Moving map with non-overlapping window

Tags: filtering, map, partitions, smoothing

How can I apply a function to a list with non-overlapping window. E.g. $data  = \{x_1, x_2, ...., x_n\}$ and we apply f with window size 2 to get $\{f(x_1,x_2), f(x_3, x_4), ...., f(x_{n-1}. x_n)\}$.

I understand that I can partition and use map on the partitioned list. But are there more efficient ways to handle this operation?

Comment: [BlockMap](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html)?

Comment: Pre-version 10.2, you can do `f /@ Partition[Range[10], 2]`.

Comment: Yes, that might be as efficient as BlockMap. I was just thinking that there should be a direct implementation. As I see it was only from v 10.2 up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = Range[10];
BlockMap[f, data, 2]

(* {f[{1, 2}], f[{3, 4}], f[{5, 6}], f[{7, 8}], f[{9, 10}]} *)
```